# How can I check the partition name in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, partition, fdisk

I am currently running my server in the rescue mode, due to the firewall issues. In order to disable the firewall thing I would have to mount the `/` partition.

My problem is that I dont know/remember what is the partition name to mount. I though that would be the `/dev/ada0` (as on my similar server bought at the same time) but there is no such partition:

```
mount /dev/ada0 /mnt
mount: /dev/ada0: Invalid argument
```

[OVH web tutorial](http://help.ovh.co.uk/RescueMode) is saying that its possible to check the partition table via the `fdisk -l` command - however, wont work on the FreeBSD:

```
# fdisk -l
fdisk: illegal option -- l
```

Is there an other possibility to check the partition table?

Comment: Firewall issue? Why not just boot in Single User Mode???

Comment: try to look at `gpart show`

Comment: or "gpart list", if you want tonns of info.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice work-around for that if anyone would be interested:

Go to the `# sade` then choose ***Label***. Everything will be shown nicely. Once finished you may exit with `Q`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
 as @DeerHunter points out, **I answered the wrong question**.  Read on if you want to know how to find out the last mount point a file system was mounted at.

It (the last mount point) is printed at the beginning of the fsck output.  Lke this:

```
root@machine:~ # fsck_ufs /dev/md4
** /dev/md4 (NO WRITE)
** Last Mounted on /db
** Phase 1 - Check Blocks and Sizes
** Phase 2 - Check Pathnames
** Phase 3 - Check Connectivity
** Phase 4 - Check Reference Counts
** Phase 5 - Check Cyl groups
1246 files, 83601532 used, 671851607 free (623 frags, 83981373 blocks, 0.0% fragmentation)
```

Comment: Have you noticed that you have to provide the partition name to `fsck` to get it back?

Comment: @DeerHunter my mistake, I thought he wanted to know the last mount point, not the device.